# Why does git allow deletion of a remote branch with unmerged changes but not a local one?

Tags: git

Running `git branch -d unmergedbranch` results in an error because git doesn't allow deletion of local branches with unmerged changes (to prevent a user accidentally losing work that hasn't been merged).  Why doesn't this also apply to remote branches with unmerged changes (`git push --delete origin unmergedbranch`)?  Is it because git assumes there will be a local branch that corresponds to the remote branch, so deleting the remote on its own won't lose any work?

Comment: You can delete a local unmerged branch if you use the ```-D``` flag instead of ```-d```.

Comment: What command are you using to delete a remote branch? (This will help determine if it's a remote tracking branch or the actual remote branch.)

Comment: @TTT I just updated the question to clarify

Comment: What's the meaning of "why" in your question? I can't seem to assign it any coherent semantic significance. Git commands are what they are, and they do what they do. End of story. Or are you asking for the history of decision making that resulted in the behavior of the commands you cite? Who would know that, and what good would it do _you_ to know it?

Comment: I explained why in my question. Why doesn't the logic of warning about deleting a local branch apply to remotes?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does git allow deletion of a remote branch with unmerged changes but not a local one?

First of all, Git does "allow" deletion of an unmerged local branch too. Perhaps a better wording of the question would be something like:

> Why does Git have an option to warn about deleting unmerged local branches but not warn for upstream branches?

Because they're conceptually different, and use different commands with different options. When deleting a local branch, the command option of lowercase `-d`:

```
git branch -d branch-name
```

[is documented as](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---delete):

> Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in `HEAD` if no upstream was set with `--track` or `--set-upstream-to`.

You can use `-D` to override that check. Note for an upstream branch that check wouldn't make sense because it already *is* the upstream branch. Also, the command used for deleting the upstream branch is `git push` which is conceptually different than the `branch` command. When you add `--delete` to `push` you are deleting a ref, which may not necessarily be a branch.

As for this additional question:

> Is it because git assumes there will be a local branch that corresponds to the remote branch, so deleting the remote on its own won't lose any work?

Note you can still delete upstream branches created by other people that you never checked out locally. Regarding losing work though, even unreferenced commits generally hang around for at least 90 days by default, and on many centralized Git server SCM tools, pushed commits stay around indefinitely even though clones may not receive them.